# How to convert mov to swf?

Tags: file-conversion, encoding

I have a QuickTime .mov file which I want to convert to swf format. Is there any tool for Mac? I already search here for a similar question but couldn't find any. The google search directed me to VisualHub which was discontinued and doesn't support Snow Leopard.

Is there a method using an Adobe CS5 app? If not what are the free solutions out there?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I found an answer on Adobe website. For those who are interested, here is the [link](http://www.adobe.com/designcenter/tutorials/videoencoderwizard/).

Comment: If this solved your problem, don't forget to make it as Accepted by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.videotoflashmac.com/

That's just a simple google search.

You can also use compressor to encode to h.264 and then change the file extension to .flv